# ¿Como obtener el value del select en React con useState?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Estoy intentando obtener el **value** del **select** para setearle el valor a la variable **typeOp** del **useState**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si elijo la opcion **egreso**, por consola **muestra "ingreso"** y si seguidamente elijo la opcion **ingreso**
por consola **muestra "egreso"**. ¿Por qué sucede esto?

aca mi código:

```js
const [typeOp, setTypeOp] = React.useState('ingreso');


const captureType = (e) => {
  setTypeOp(e.target.value);
  console.log(typeOp);
}

return (

  <Form.Control as="select" onChange={captureType}>
      <option value={typeOp}>Ingreso</option>
      <option value="egreso">Egreso</option>
  </Form.Control>

);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese problema en parte es porque ese `console.log()` te muestra el valor del estado `typeOp` antes de ser seteado.

Si pondrías el `console.log()` entre el `captureType` y el `return` podrías ver el estado ya actualizado.

Pero aun haciendo eso todavía habría un error por corregir.

El problema principal es el `value` que le estás poniendo al primer `<option>`.

No debería ser `{typeOp}` porque así como está tomará el valor del estado que cuando llegue a tener el valor de "Egreso" ya no volverá a cambiar más.

Para corregirlo deberías cambiar el `value` de la primer opción y la posición del `console.log()` así:

```
const [typeOp, setTypeOp] = React.useState('ingreso');

const captureType = (e) => {
    setTypeOp(e.target.value);
}

console.log(typeOp);

return (

    <Form.Control as="select" onChange={captureType}>
        <option value="ingreso">Ingreso</option>
        <option value="egreso">Egreso</option>
    </Form.Control>

);
```

Comment: gracias @Desarrollos-Web-Urquiza funciona correctamente!